# Encoding URIs with foreign characters

Tags: url, encoding, uri

1. I want to display characters like "é,ë,ñ,עברית" as is in the urls. How can I do that?
   When I type something like "page.php?name=é" it turns the url into "page.php?name=%E9", not what I desire.
2. There seems to be a problem with .htaccess when rewriting the url, it would just output error message. How can I fix it? (this is the rule btw):

   > RewriteRule ^(/`*`[a-zA-Z0-9\%]`*`)$    /page.php?name=$1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to RFC 1738 this isnt possible.

http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

This is an excellent reference page explaining it in laymans terms.

Comment: That's strange, because if I type: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%C3%A9&search_type=&aq=f
it immediately modifies it to 'é' and so with other chars as well.

Comment: The browser may be doing the substitution because of your regional  character encoding.  I suggest looking at it in wireshark I'm guessing  that the transmitted data doesnt contain the special characters.

Comment: +1 to Mech's answer and comment. Looked at this site http://www.worldjournal.com/category/美國/ in wireshark,The 美國 characters go over the wire as %E7%BE%8E%E5%9C%8B.